# Why does docker build copy entrypoint script as root user?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I copy `entrypoint.sh` to the home directory after having switched user, why does `docker build` still assign it to the `root` user:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ARG user=hakond
ARG home=/home/$user
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash $user \
        && echo $user:ubuntu | chpasswd \
        && adduser $user sudo
WORKDIR $home
USER $user
COPY entrypoint.sh $home
RUN ls -l entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

If I build this (as user `hakon`) the output is:

```
$ ls -l entrypoint.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hakon hakon 24 juli   8 14:16 entrypoint.sh
$ echo $USER
hakon
$ docker build -t debug_entrypoint .
[...]
Step 8/10 : COPY entrypoint.sh $home
 ---> 5f6d16e80d2c
Step 9/10 : RUN ls -l entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in ee919e65e860
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24 Jul  8 12:16 entrypoint.sh
[...]
```

Notice that the file `entrypoint.sh` is owned by `root` (not by `hakond` as I would expect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional flag --chown=: with either the ADD or COPY commands.

[chown docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

As copy command use `root` user by default.

```
COPY --chown=$user entrypoint.sh $home
```

output should be

```
Step 13/14 : RUN ls -l entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 231123a8899b
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hakond hakond 0 Jul  8 14:28 entrypoint.sh
```